# How to substract 2 char in javascript to get a difference in ascii

Tags: javascript, char

`alert('g' - 'a')` is returning Not a Number. ('NAN').

But I expect, to get the difference between `ascii` as `alert(103-97)` => `alert(6)`. Hence `6` to be output.

In C, `int i = 'g' - 'a'`, will give `i = 6`.

How to achieve this subtraction of 2 characters in javascript? (easily without much effort as below)

`alert("g".charCodeAt(0) - "a".charCodeAt(0))` is giving 6.

Application : I am using this in chess program.

Comment: Wait, `.charCodeAt(0)` is "much effort"?

Comment: just like that. that is the way

Comment: **TL;DR:** `'A'.charCodeAt(0)` and the reverse: `String.fromCharCode(65)`

Comment: **Also note:** using `letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; letters[index]` is way faster if you're doing this in batch.

Answer (score 26):

The only practicable way to do as you want is the way you've already suggested:

```
alert('g'.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0));
```

As you know, this will retrieve the ASCII character code from 0th element of the string in each case, and subtract the second from the first.

Unfortunately this is the only way to retrieve the ASCII code of a given character, though using a function would be somewhat simpler, though given the brevity/simplicity of the `charCodeAt()` solution not all that much so.

References:

- [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't treat characters as numbers; they are single-character strings instead. So the subtract operator will be calculating `Number('g') - Number('a')`.

You should do `'g'.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)` (there is no better way, but you can wrap it in a function)

Answer (score 0):

You can write yourself a custom function. Something like this:

```
function asciiDif(a,b) {
    return a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0);
}
```

And then:

```
alert(asciiDif('g','a'));
```